# Why are public variables lost after an error?

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox, collections

I have developed the following two subs which create and remove a collection of checkboxes next to a listobject. Each distinct ID in the listobject gets a checkbox. Like this I can approve the listobject entries.

The code is the follwing:

```
Public CBcollection As Collection
Public CTRLcollection As Collection

Sub create_chbx()
If Approval.CBcollection Is Nothing Then
Dim i As Integer
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim CTRL As Excel.OLEObject
Dim CB As MSForms.CheckBox
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim L As Double, T As Double, H As Double, W As Double
Dim rng As Range
Dim ID As Long, oldID As Long

Set CBcollection = New Collection
Set CTRLcollection = New Collection
Set sht = ActiveSheet
Set tbl = sht.ListObjects("ApprovalTBL")
Set rng = tbl.Range(2, 1).Offset(0, -1)
      W = 10
      H = 10
      L = rng.Left + rng.Width / 2 - W / 2
      T = rng.Top + rng.Height / 2 - H / 2

For i = 1 To tbl.ListRows.count
      ID = tbl.Range(i + 1, 1).Value
      If Not (ID = oldID) Then
            Set CTRL = sht.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CheckBox.1", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=L, Top:=T, Width:=W, Height:=H)
            Set CB = CTRL.Object
            CBcollection.Add Item:=CB
            CTRLcollection.Add Item:=CTRL
      End If

      Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0)
      T = rng.Top + rng.Height / 2 - H / 2
      oldID = ID
Next i
End If
End Sub


Sub remove_chbx()
If Not Approval.CBcollection Is Nothing Then
With Approval.CBcollection ' Approval is the module name
      While .count > 0
            .Remove (.count)
      Wend
End With
With Approval.CTRLcollection
      While .count > 0
            .Item(.count).Delete
            .Remove (.count)
      Wend
End With
Set Approval.CBcollection = Nothing
Set Approval.CTRLcollection = Nothing
End If
End Sub
```

This all works pretty well. No double checkboxes and no errors if there are no checkboxes. I am developing an approval scheme were I need to develop and test other modules. If I now run this sub:

```
Sub IdoStupidStuff()
Dim i As Integer
Dim Im As Image

i = 1
Set Im = i
End Sub
```

It will give me an error. If I then try to run one of my checkbox subs they will not work properly anymore. The collection is deleted by the error and I am no longer able to access the collections. Why does this happen and am I able to counter act this other then just not causing errors? Is there a better way to implement such a system were loss of collections is not an issue?

Comment: That's just a normal behavior how VBA works. If you stop (not pause) the execution of the code (eg. because of an exemption) then all variables are cleared out. If you need to save data you need to put it into a worksheet, which you can read on initialization if you restart your code. Also proper error handling will prevent your code from being terminated.

Comment: All variables are lost when program terminates, one way is through errors. Read about error handling. Few words of interest are resume resume next etc.

Comment: You should change your Vba code that way, it will load the global variables each time you run the code. Do never expect Vba will keep the global variables at idel time, and due to the error it will clear all variables on turning to idel time.

Comment: @ Rolfi and @peh : How would that look like? I enter the public variable into the worksheet initialize is that all?

Comment: Yes put all persistent values into a worksheet and read them every time before you run your code. Eg. you can check if your public variable is empty, if so read from the worksheet otherwise use the variable. There are many ways it's up to you how you implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap the Collection object in a Property and let it handle the object creation:

```
Private mCollection As Collection

Public Property Get TheCollection() As Collection
    If mCollection Is Nothing Then Set mCollection = New Collection
    Set TheCollection = mCollection
End Property
```

To call it:

```
TheCollection.Count
```

Comment: Nice to know! After all of the people who told me it is not possible finally a solution. I already thought of just using the OLEObjects collection of the worksheet and manually making sure only the right objects get deleted. Thank you!

Comment: Trying to use this interestingly looking approach I found that it is only accessible from withing the module. I've put it in the MS Access VBA code in form on-load event. But trying to call it from any other module I get "variable not defined". What a pity, that was really nice looking solution...

Comment: @Smok The form's code behind file is private to the form used to handle control events, hence the no-access. If you want application-wide access, you have to put it in a standard module. Then it can be accessed using `ModuleName.TheCollection`.

Comment: Great tip! Even more, it seems that using module name is not necessary! looks like it's enough to call it using `TheCollection`. That's good enough for me. You saved me a lot of time with my configuration module.

Comment: @Smok Indeed it's not necessary, but helps you find the module where the property/method resides. Also, if you have 2 properties/methods with the same name (in different modules of course), then the module name is required to resolve the conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Try `On Error Resume Next` before the line that causes the error. It will skip the problem and your vairables will still be available.
However this will not solve your error. Try to make a seperate hidden sheet in your workbook to store your global variables so they won't go missing.
f.ex.:

```
Private Sub CreateSheet()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set ws = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
        ws.Name = "Global"
        .Worksheets("Global").Visible = False
    End With
End Sub
```